# Wordpress shortcodes do not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site that has been modified before me quite a bit. So now the short code does not work. If I put in [gallery] it will just print out [gallery] in the page. Does any one know what could be wrong. Maybe I need to replace some files with the unmodified ones?
Which file is responsible for shortcodes?

Comment: what browser do you use? you may try in chrome ctrl+shift+j (opens the console) to see in console if there are any errors

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode perhaps?

Comment: There is a jquery error which i dont think is related

Comment: here is the site http://www.jmcreativecraft.com/?page_id=1675

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something to process the shortcode, it would not just process gallery. You need to have a gallery plugin that replaces this short code with the actual gallery. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I do have a plugin. and Gallery is just the default wp short code

Comment: what plugin are you using? Give me a link please.

Comment: i don't think its the plugin because if i use the default wp [gallery] code that doesn't work ether

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot more specific detail it's hard to say what is wrong, but here's one WAG (Wild Ass Guess):

The shortcode 'parser' is actually a poorly written regexp than can get confused in a number of situations. One particular situation is when you have something like

```
blah blah blah [shortcode1][shortcode2] blah blah
```

i.e. one shortcode immediately after the other, no space. The first one is executed, and the second one is left as-is, meaning it will show up as literally [shortcode2] on the page.

Comment: there is only one shortcode on that page and none of the shortcodes work from this or any other plugin

Comment: @Ross: Is it just on this one page, or do all pages show this behavior? If you create/add a simple test shortcode, does it work? Is there any code in `functions.php` (or anywhere else) that is *disabling* shortcodes?

Comment: all i had to do is add 
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11); to the functions.php

Comment: @Ross: Which you shouldn't have had to do. That means that something (somewhere) disabled your shortcode processing. You might want to look at that and clean it up before the next poor soul has to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is to add the following: "
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11); " to functions.php and it worked